# Search string and delete everythig else and paste to new file with Powershell

Tags: string, powershell

In main directory "Movies" I have multiple directories with "Movie Name" and each directory contain "movie_name.nfo" file.

```
Movies
  |- Avatar
       - Avatar.nfo
  |- Ad Astra
       - Ad Astra.nfo
```

In those "movie_name.nfo" files I have multiple links and each link is stored in separated line:

```
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt8134742/
https://www.themoviedb.org/movie/489064/
http://www.csfd.cz/film/603376
```

What I want is:

If "movie_name.nfo" file contain string "themoviedb", then everything else is deleted in that file except that line which contain searched string. Every lines which was deleted (not contain searched string) are copied to new file with name "movie.nfo" in same folder as is "movie_name.nfo" file.

I tried several options, but without success, this is what I have now,

```
Get-Content -Path "./*" -Filter *.nfo -Recurse | Where {$_ -notmatch "themoviedb"} | Set-Content "movie.nfo"
```

Thank you.

Comment: Don't you get errors when you run this code snippet? `Get-Content` does not have a parameter `-Recurse`. Try to run the first part of your pipeline seperatley.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the movie info files always have the same basename like their folder you can use a loop to

1. "construct" the target file name with [Join-Path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/join-path?view=powershell-5.1)
2. check if the file contains the pattern with [Select-String](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?view=powershell-5.1)
3. if there's a match remove all other lines with [Select-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-5.1)
4. if not create a new file containing the pattern with [Out-File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file?view=powershell-5.1)

You could start with something like this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path .\movies -Directory |
ForEach-Object {
    $Pattern = 'themoviedb'
    $FileName = Join-Path -Path $_.FullName -ChildPath ($_.BaseName + '.nfo')
    $tempResult = Select-String -Path $FileName -Pattern $Pattern 
    if ($tempResult) {
        $Content = Get-Content -Path $FileName
        $Content | 
            Select-Object -Skip ($tempResult.LineNumber - 1) -First 1 |
                Set-Content -Path $FileName -Force
        $nfoFileName = Join-Path -Path $_.FullName -ChildPath 'movie.nfo'
        $newContent = $Content |
            Select-Object -First ($tempResult.LineNumber - 1) |
                Out-String
        $newContent += $Content |
            Select-Object -Skip ($tempResult.LineNumber) |
                Out-String
        $newContent |
            Out-File -FilePath $nfoFileName
    }
    else {
        $nfoFileName = Join-Path -Path $_.FullName -ChildPath 'movie.nfo'
        $Pattern | 
            Out-File -FilePath $nfoFileName
    }
}
```

I'd recommend to read always the complete help for the cmdlets you use ... including the examples to learn how to use them.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, but code work only at half as I want, maybe I don't explain correctly with my english sorry. What I want is, every line which not contain string "themoviedb" must be always writed to file movie.nfo and same time line with string "themoviedb" will be stored in same file as was, but everything else in that file file will be deleted. Your code find string "themoviedb" and delete everything in that file, that is ok, but what is deleted is not stored in movie.nfo, or when string is not finded, only string is writed to movie.nfo and nothing else.  Thank you.

Comment: So please update your question accordingly. If we don't know what you're actually trying to do we cannot help. Please keep in mind: we cannot see your screen and we cannot read your mind.  You might (re-)read the help topic [reprex](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  
 ..... Regardless of that my code snippet actually has everything to show how to go forward. Why don't you tweak it for your needs yourself?

Comment: Question is updated I hope, I tryed tweak your code, but it is too compicated for me. Thank you.

Comment: I changed the code in my answer accordingly. But listen: I think it is beyond the scope of StackOverflow or any other forum to iteratively develop a ready to use solution for you. Nor it is the scope of any forum to teach you how to write a script in a particular scripting language. If you're not experienced enough to understand the help you get you should do a step back and start to learn the basics of Powershell from scratch. You cannot learn a complex technology by asking arbitrary questions in forum or by copying snippets from the internet - you have to have a basic knowledge.